# How to make a folder a non Git directory?

Tags: git, terminal

One day I was messing around with Git and I accidentally made a folder Git repository so now it looks like this:

```
⌘ ~/sites/ (master)
```

How can I change it back to a regular folder?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
rm -rf .git
```

Removing this folder will make it a non git directory. Maybe accidentally someone previously by doing *git init* initialized a git repository here.